# I get a "Non static method" error after upgrading to PHP 8.1

Tags: php, php-8.1

I have the following PHP error after upgrading from PHP7.4 to PHP8.1

```
$result = CarsDAO::selectCarsByColor($idCar, self::CARS_PER_PAGE, 0);
```

`Non static method 'selectCarsByColor' should not be called statically`

Any ideas how to rewrite this to be OK?

Comment: As the error says: Make the function static in CarsDAO class or create an instance first and call method on it.

Comment: Currently have no idea how to do that. Any pointers?

Comment: I would just add it here for whoever downvoted and all that the answer by @MarkusZeller helped me and I was able to save hours of trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, the method is not static in the CarsDAO class, so you should call it on an instance.

```
$car    = new CarsDAO();
$result = $car->selectCarsByColor($idCar, self::CARS_PER_PAGE, 0);
```

Dirty one-liner

```
$result = (new CarsDAO)->selectCarsByColor($idCar, self::CARS_PER_PAGE, 0);
```

or **repair** the class by making the method **static** adding the `static` keyword in front of the method declaration. [Read about static in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

```
class CarsDAO {
    public static function selectCarsByColor($idCar, $carsPerPage, $zeroThing) {
    // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: `$zeroThing` :)